# Gather same years in a dataframe in r?

Tags: r

There are two years (2011 and 2012) information in my data. I want to gather same years as shown in the output part. And I want the output as dataframe as shown below.

*Here is my sample data which contains different years;*

```
$`01-2011`
         [,1]
    m5  0.266
    m10 0.532
    m15 0.797
    m30 1.092
    h1  1.270
    h2  1.270
    h3  1.270
    h4  1.460
    h5  1.460
    h6  2.340
    h8  2.530
    h12 2.530
    h18 2.530
    h24 2.530

    $`02-2011`
          [,1]
    m5   0.955
    m10  1.683
    m15  2.398
    m30  4.539
    h1   6.528
    h2   9.427
    h3  10.848
    h4   9.543
    h5  13.736
    h6  16.635
    h8  16.751
    h12 16.751
    h18 16.751
    h24 16.751

    $`01-2012`
          [,1]
    m5   1.224
    m10  2.395
    m15  3.063
    m30  5.131
    h1   7.112
    h2   9.474
    h3   9.474
    h4  10.302
    h5  10.744
    h6   9.474
    h8  12.490
    h12 11.406
    h18 13.571
    h24 13.919

    $`03-2012`
          [,1]
    m5   0.750
    m10  1.391
    m15  1.871
    m30  3.649
    h1   5.174
    h2   6.275
    h3   6.439
    h4   8.396
    h5   6.963
    h6  10.453
    h8   8.844
    h12 10.453
    h18 10.901
    h24 10.901
```

*And the sample data's structure:*

```
data<-list(`01-2011` = structure(c(0.266, 0.532, 0.797, 1.092, 1.27, 
    1.27, 1.27, 1.46, 1.46, 2.34, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53), .Dim = c(14L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", 
    "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)), `02-2011` = structure(c(0.955, 
    1.683, 2.398, 4.539, 6.528, 9.427, 10.848, 9.543, 13.736, 16.635, 
    16.751, 16.751, 16.751, 16.751), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
        "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)), `01-2012` = structure(c(1.224, 
    2.395, 3.063, 5.131, 7.112, 9.474, 9.474, 10.302, 10.744, 9.474, 
    12.49, 11.406, 13.571, 13.919), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
        "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)), `03-2012` = structure(c(0.75, 
    1.391, 1.871, 3.649, 5.174, 6.275, 6.439, 8.396, 6.963, 10.453, 
    8.844, 10.453, 10.901, 10.901), .Dim = c(14L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("m5", "m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", 
        "h6", "h8", "h12", "h18", "h24"), NULL)))
```

*Here is the desired output;*

```
     2011  2012
m5  0.266 0.955
m10 0.532 1.683
m15 0.797 2.398
m30 1.092 4.539
h1  1.270 6.528
h2  1.270 9.427
      .     .
```

*And the structure of desired output;*

```
output<-structure(list(`2011` = c(0.266, 0.532, 0.797, 1.092, 1.27, 1.27, 
1.27, 1.46, 1.46, 2.34, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53, 2.53), `2012` = c(0.955, 
1.683, 2.398, 4.539, 6.528, 9.427, 10.848, 9.543, 13.736, 16.635, 
16.751, 16.751, 16.751, 16.751)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("m5", 
"m10", "m15", "m30", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h8", 
"h12", "h18", "h24"))
```

Comment: This question is not clear, has insufficient detail, and the desired output is incomplete. Also, the accepted answer does not give the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)
   library(purrr)
   data_df <- as.data.frame(data)%>% 
     tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "var") %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -var, names_to = "Year") %>% 
     mutate(Year = stringr::str_extract(Year, "\\d{4}$")) %>% 
     group_by(var, Year) %>% 
     summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
     pivot_wider(id_cols = -value, names_from = Year, values_from = value) %>% 
     ungroup()
```

Comment: One drawback of this approach, is that it will fail if each element of the list does not have the same number or rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`, `purrr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate`.

You have two columns for each year, yet your desired output has only one column for each year, so I took the mean of the two months. If you prefer some other summarizing function, simply edit `summarize(mean = mean(V1))` to be some other operation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
map(data,~ rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(.x))) %>%
  bind_rows(.,.id= "date") %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0("01-", date),format = "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%
  mutate(year = year(date)) %>%
  group_by(year,rowname) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(V1)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "rowname", names_from = "year",values_from = "mean")
#   rowname `2011` `2012`
#   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 h1       3.90   6.14 
# 2 h12      9.64  10.9  
# 3 h18      9.64  12.2  
# 4 h2       5.35   7.87 
# 5 h24      9.64  12.4  
# 6 h3       6.06   7.96 
# 7 h4       5.50   9.35 
# 8 h5       7.60   8.85 
# 9 h6       9.49   9.96 
#10 h8       9.64  10.7  
#11 m10      1.11   1.89 
#12 m15      1.60   2.47 
#13 m30      2.82   4.39 
#14 m5       0.610  0.987
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method where we `split` the data into a `list` of data.frame by making use of the `substring` of the `names` of the `list`, then loop over the `list`, `cbind` the inner `list` elements, get the `rowMeans` and `cbind` the outer `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split(data, substring(names(data), 4)) %>%
   map(~ do.call(cbind, .x) %>% rowMeans) %>% 
   do.call(cbind, .)
#     2011    2012
#m5  0.6105  0.9870
#m10 1.1075  1.8930
#m15 1.5975  2.4670
#m30 2.8155  4.3900
#h1  3.8990  6.1430
#h2  5.3485  7.8745
#h3  6.0590  7.9565
#h4  5.5015  9.3490
#h5  7.5980  8.8535
#h6  9.4875  9.9635
#h8  9.6405 10.6670
#h12 9.6405 10.9295
#h18 9.6405 12.2360
#h24 9.6405 12.4100
```

---

Or the same in `base R`, we `split` the data as above, loop over the `list` with `sapply`, get the `rowMeans` of the `cbind`ed inner `list` elements

```
sapply(split(data, substring(names(data), 4)), 
       function(x) rowMeans(do.call(cbind, x)))
#      2011    2012
#m5  0.6105  0.9870
#m10 1.1075  1.8930
#m15 1.5975  2.4670
#m30 2.8155  4.3900
#h1  3.8990  6.1430
#h2  5.3485  7.8745
#h3  6.0590  7.9565
#h4  5.5015  9.3490
#h5  7.5980  8.8535
#h6  9.4875  9.9635
#h8  9.6405 10.6670
#h12 9.6405 10.9295
#h18 9.6405 12.2360
#h24 9.6405 12.4100
```

NOTE: Both solutions show the same output as the other solutions